# Hide Google reCAPTCHA V3 badge

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

I know that I can hide Google reCAPTCHA V3 badge since I include the reCAPTCHA branding visibly in the user flow.

My question is, if I have more than one form in my website, I have to include the reCAPTCHA branding in all forms or I just need to mention it a single time?

I tried to find some information about it in the documentation but I didn't find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If all your forms are on a single page or if the user flow clearly indicates that reCAPTCHA is being used across the site, a single, prominently placed mention might suffice. However, if your forms are on different pages or if it's not obvious that reCAPTCHA is used site-wide, it's advisable to include a mention at each form.

Comment: It's a multipage website and I have some forms so I will include the reCAPTCHA branding in all forms. Thank you.